# Can't log in on server

Tags: 16.04, server, gnome, login

We've got a server Ubuntu. 16.04.2 LTS with a gnome gui.

But we can't log in on the server itself.
Can't find any problems. Can login via ssh and via the ip as well. but not on the server itself.

After entering the password it gets back to the login screen. It doesn't gives a fault when entering the correct password. nothing. It won't login.

What can be done in order to login on the Server itself?

Comment: which user are you using? root? regular user?

Comment: Check in the home of the user:`.Xauthority` user and group MUST be the username equal to what you use to login. And also check `.xsession-errors` . That is the file that holds errors that occur during logging in.

Comment: Regeluar user, only have 1 user on it.

Comment: where do i find those files?

Comment: Shift to console (`shift-alt-f2`) and log in there. Then you can check `.xauthority`and other files.

Comment: @Redhairedman "Check in the home of the user" So in /home/$USER/

Comment: The file kept giving an error, (couldn t reach .xauthority) so I chose to remove the gui of the server. Everything looks fine now.

Comment: I did and then tried: 
-> login in screen then pressed Ctrl + Alt + f1
->  Sudo su-
->  cd ~ 
->   ls -la
->   mv .Xauthority Xauthority.backup
->   touch .Xauthority
->  .Xauthority

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Content:

-->HOST=`hostname`
-->key=`perl -e 'srand; printf int(rand(100000000000000000))'`
-->key=$key$key
-->xauth add ${HOST}/unix:0 . $key
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-->after that restart but loop stayed.